# How to run query with parameters against a database whose name is in a variable using sp_ExecuteSql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sp-executesql

I am working with **Microsoft SQL Server 2016** in **Windows Server 2016**.

I have a query with 1 parameter, string type.

```
select PH.project_name, PD.employee_id, E.first_name, E.last_name 
from project_header PH 
inner join project_detail PD on PD.project_id = PH.project_id
inner join employee E on E.employee_id = PD.employee_id
where PH.project_name = @ProjectName
order by 1, 2;
```

where `@ProjectName` is varchar(50) type.

I have to write a proc which receives 2 arguments: database name and project name:

```
@a_database_name varchar(100),
@a_project_name varchar(50)
```

I want to run the above query passing `@a_project_name` as parameter to the query. And I want to run the query against the database provided in `@a_database_name` variable using `sp_executeSQL`. How can I do that?

I know how to perform this task without `sp_executeSQL`. I want to know how to do it with `sp_executeSQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below SQL to create that procedure:

```
create procedure ProcName  @a_database_name varchar(100),@a_project_name varchar(50)
as
begin

EXEC('USE ' + @a_database_name + ';select PH.project_name, PD.employee_id, E.first_name, E.last_name 
from project_header PH 
inner join project_detail PD on PD.project_id = PH.project_id
inner join employee E on E.employee_id = PD.employee_id
where PH.project_name= '+@a_project_name+'  order by 1, 2;')
end
```

But it has SQL injection risk- if `@a_database_name` is provided contains in it `";DROP DATABASE"`. But if you trust the system that is calling this procedure you are good to go.

Or you might use below query without "use databasename" in it:

```
create procedure ProcName  @a_database_name varchar(100),@a_project_name varchar(50)
as
begin

EXEC('select PH.project_name, PD.employee_id, E.first_name, E.last_name 
from '+@a_database_name+'.dbo.project_header PH 
inner join project_detail PD on PD.project_id = PH.project_id
inner join employee E on E.employee_id = PD.employee_id
where PH.project_name= '+@a_project_name+'  order by 1, 2;')
end
```

**Query with sp_executesql:**

```
create procedure ProcName  @a_database_name varchar(100),@a_project_name varchar(50)
as
begin
DECLARE  @SqlStatment AS NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @SqlStatment = 'select PH.project_name, PD.employee_id, E.first_name, E.last_name 
from '+@a_database_name+'.dbo.project_header PH 
inner join project_detail PD on PD.project_id = PH.project_id
inner join employee E on E.employee_id = PD.employee_id
where PH.project_name= @a_project_name  order by 1, 2;'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SqlStatment ,N'@a_project_name varchar',@a_project_name


end
```

**Revised Answer:**

```
create procedure ProcName  @a_database_name varchar(100),@a_project_name varchar(50)
as
begin

declare @sp_executesql as nvarchar(1000)

SELECT @sp_executesql = quotename(@a_database_name) + '.sys.sp_executesql'
EXEC @sp_executesql N'select PH.project_name, PD.employee_id, E.first_name, E.last_name 
from project_header PH inner join project_detail PD on PD.project_id = PH.project_id
inner join employee E on E.employee_id = PD.employee_id
where PH.project_name= @a_project_name  order by 1, 2;',N'@a_project_name nvarchar(100)', @a_project_name;

end
```

Comment: But this solution is not using `sp_executeSQL`. I prefer a solution which uses `sp_executeSQL`

Comment: @srh please check now whether I got you right or not.

Comment: not working. Also I want `@a_database_name` parameterized like `@a_project_name`

Comment: Database is sql server. Right?

Comment: @srh If I am not wrong then you can not use database name like I use project name as parameter. But it can be done in slightly different way. I have updated my answer.

Comment: U are most welcome. Thanks for accepting my answer. If you feel comfortable an upvote will be appreciated.